# Network Data Packet connectivity intent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, connectivity

I am writing an Android application which can enable and disable the Network Data packet connection. I am also using one broadcast receiver to check the Network Data packet connection. I have registered broadcast receiver and provided required permission in Manifest file. But when I run this application it changes the connection state and after that it crashes. But when I don't include this broadcast receiver it works fine. I am not able to see any kind of log which can provide some clue.

Here is my code for broadcast receiver.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rakesh.simplewidget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <!-- Permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SimpleWidgetExampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--
        <receiver
            android:name=".ExampleAppWidgetProvider"
            android:label="Widget ErrorBuster" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget1_info" />
        </receiver>
        -->
        <receiver android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My Broadcast receiver class is as following.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;


public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo)intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if(info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){ 
            if(info.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
                Log.e("RK","Mobile data is connected");
            }else{
                Log.e("RK","Mobile data is disconnected");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

my Main activity file.

```
package com.rakesh.simplewidget;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimpleWidgetExampleActivity extends Activity {
    private Button btNetworkSetting;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btNetworkSetting = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btNetworkSetting);
        if(checkConnectivityState(getApplicationContext())){
            btNetworkSetting.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }else{
            btNetworkSetting.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        }
    }

    public void openNetworkSetting(View view){

        Method dataConnSwitchmethod;
        Class telephonyManagerClass;
        Object ITelephonyStub;
        Class ITelephonyClass;
        Context context = view.getContext();
        boolean enabled = !checkConnectivityState(context);
        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);


        try{
            final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
            final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
            iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
            final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
            final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
            final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);

            if(enabled){
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Enabled Network Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Disabled Network Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Error", "some error");
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "It didn't work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkConnectivityState(Context context){
        final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        ConnectivityManager af ;
        return telephonyManager.getDataState() == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED;

    }
}
```

Log file:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.rakesh.simplewidget.ConnectivityReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rakesh.simplewidget.ConnectivityReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.rakesh.simplewidget-2.apk]
E/AndroidRuntime(26094):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1777)
E/AndroidRuntime(26094):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(26094):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
E/AndroidRuntime(26094):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(26094):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(26094):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
E/AndroidRuntime(26094):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26094):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(26094):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
E/AndroidRuntime(26094):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
E/AndroidRuntime(26094):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It seems Android is not able to recognize file Broadcast Receiver class. Any idea why I am getting this error?

PS: Some information about Android environment and platform.
 - Android API 10.
 - Running on Samsung Galaxy II which has android 2.3.6

Edit:

my broadcast receiver file ConnectivityReceiver.java was present in default package and it was not being recognized by Android. Android was looking for this file in current package i.e `com.rakesh.simplewidget;` I just moved connectivityReciever.java file to `com.rakesh.simplewidget` package and problem was solved.

Comment: Its running fine at my end.Show your complete manifest.xml

Comment: @VipulShah I am not able to see proper log. There is something wrong with my eclipse

Comment: @VipulShah I got the log file by help of logcat. But its really long don't know how to share here. Can you please provide some idea.? Please check the updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Broadcast receiver file `ConnectivityReceiver.java` was present in default package by mistake. And Android was not able to recognized this file because it was searching `ConnectivityReceiver` in the current package. i.e `com.rakesh.simplewidget;`

It was simple unnoticeable mistake which caused me half an hour to debug this.

Thank you guys for taking time reading my question and providing your comments.

Updated the main post.